# Page looks abnormal when i minimize my browser window size

Tags: css, html

I was learning html from internet and this is what i tried

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <body>
       <table cellspacing="0" style="margin-left:250px;margin-top:100px">
           <tr><td style="background-color:#EBEBF5;font-size:15px">Profile Info </td></tr>
           <tr><td>Sports & Fun</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Add More</td></tr>
       </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ok This ouputs as like these when my window is in maximized

```
  Profile Info
  Sports & Fun 
  Add More
```

Now I have minimized my window and starting compressing it smaller and when i made the window compress and more smaller.

The output is like these

```
   Profile
   Info
   Sports
   & Fun
   Add 
   More
```

I thought this behavior is may be due to making window size smaller then i started expermenting on google,facebook, stackoverflow websites, Though I made their window size smaller they were still looking like before with increased scroll bar at the bottom. I wondered why its not working with mine.

Can anyone help me with these ? How can i make my html page look like as it was i mean look same when window is in maximized and even when not maximized ? I want my html page look same even when it is minimized to minimum,like these

```
  Profile Info
  Sports & Fun 
  Add More
```

Comment: Find better places to learn from. You seem to have discovered [layout tables](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/everything.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML pages resize to fit the window size. If you don't want that, specify the `width`:

```
<table cellspacing="0" style="margin-left:250px;margin-top:100px; width:250px">
```

Comment: width? but will it work if i have different screen resolutions, i mean different screens with different sizes?

Comment: I don't understand why you're answering such a low-quality and too-specific question?

Comment: questions never be stupid unless they are stupid people - Albert Einstein please dont discourage me saying that its a low quality question ! thanks

Comment: @omouse - Why wouldn't I? Everyone starts somewhere. If you have a problem with the question, tell them how to fix it.

Comment: @niko - If you set the width, it will *always* be that width, no matter what the page size is. There's a `min-width` property, but last time I checked, it's not well supported.

Comment: @BrendanLong its not working for float:left i will post another question please help me with that too !

Answer (score 0):

you should use the ***min-width***.
like this:

```
<html><head><style>body{min-width: (value);}</style></head></html>
```